# What does "\1" represent in this Java string?

Tags: java, regex, unicode-escapes

```
System.out.println("\1");
```

I thought it did not compile because of the non-recognized escape sequence.

What does `"\1"` exactly represent?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's an octal escape sequence, as listed in [section 3.10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) of the JLS. So for example:

```
String x = "\16";
```

is equivalent to:

```
String x = "\u000E";
```

(As Octal 16 = Hex E.)

So `\1` us U+0001, the "start of heading" character.

Octal escape sequences are very rarely used in Java in my experience, and I'd personally avoid them where possible. When I want to specify a character using a numeric escape sequence, I always use `\uxxxx`.

Comment: Java is one of those languages that make you swear profusely when you hit the "incidental" bugs it has. Did you know that Java interprets character escapes to be a *literal* character in the source code? Well this isn't a problem until you try and escape a carriage return... then Java thinks you stuck a newline in your source code when you really didn't want one.

Comment: @PP.: It depends on which character escape you mean. For example, a comment of `// This \n is okay` is fine,  but `// This \u000a is not` will not compile.

Comment: Your second code line doesn't compile (on my machine at least): *"string literal is not properly closed by a double-quote"*.

Comment: Also, since Java does not have raw strings, using regular expressions with back references requires the use of `\\1`, which can be quite irritating.

Comment: I disagree with the value of using `\u`. This is because Java will interpret `\u` as starting a a hex escape sequence *anywhere in your Java code*, including in comments and identifiers. The compiler replaces the character before compiling your code, potentially leading to strange bugs. For example: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/164

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, but I don't use non-ASCII identifiers, and in a comment I'd use U+000D or something similar instead. Neither of those cases is one where "I want to specify a character using a numeric escape sequence".

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I haven't run into situations where I need to specify a non-ASCII character in Java. What I'm more afraid of is accidentally typing `\uxxxx` in a string like a file path (like the bug I posted), not deliberately using it to specify a special character.

Comment: @Kevin Just another reason not to use backslashes in path names. BTW, I guess the octal notation like also the octal int literals are there to make C programmers feel comfortable. Interestingly, octal literals are frowned upon, while hexadecimal ones are fine.

Answer (score 2):

In java It is following value

```
\u0001
```