# How to construct a valid parameter for findNodeKeyByPath()?

Tags: sap-gui, silktest

To access items in a SAP GUI GuiTree object, most methods need a key which identifies the node. To get such a key, you need the function `findNodeKeyByPath()`. The description says:

> Return the node key for the given path (e.g. 2\1\2). 
> path  The node path. STRING.

I need to get the first child of the first item in the tree. Using `"0"` throws an exception. Indexes of the root element seem to start at 1 instead of 0. Using `"1"` and `"2"` gives me correct keys.

But anything I try with a backslash does not work. `"1\0"` does not throw an exception, neither does `"1\1"`. But both parameters return the key of node `"1"` and not of a subnode.

How do I need to construct the *path* in SilkTest (Silk4J, SAP) to get a valid key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `"\1"` is the octal representation of ASCII character 0x01. See [What does \1 represent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616286/what-does-1-represent-in-this-java-string). The string `"1\\1"` gives a valid path and returns the correct key.

However, the node must be visible, otherwise an empty string is returned. That means, you need the following code:

```
SapTree tree = ...; // initialize somewhere
String parentKey = tree.findNodeKeyByPath("1");
tree.expandNode(parentKey);
String key = tree.findNodeKeyByPath("1\\1");
```