# How to ignore certain characters in a String / Stream?

Tags: java

Let's say, I write some code to print out "Hello World."

Could I use some sort of ignore list of characters to be ignored from my print string (in this case Hello World). For instance, I want to remove the r in "hello wo**r**ld" so that the output is "Hello Wold"

I have a value that I am using. I have the following characters:
&, \, and *.

I think one of these characters is causing me to have some of my values ignored.

Normally I would just test this myself, but I am not able to do this at this time.

Comment: the \ symbol is the escape character. \r is the carriage return symbol explained here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260126/what-are-the-differences-between-char-literals-n-and-r-in-java

Comment: I am using \*. Wouldn't this have no effect?

Comment: are you using this for a password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea *why* you would want to do this, but writing a method to do that isn't all that hard...

```
public static void printlnWithIgnores(String toPrint, Set<Character> ignore) {
    for(char c : toPrint.toCharArray()) {
        if(! ignore.contains(c)) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

As for that happening within a string because of a character literal, I'm not sure that it's possible. Some tests:

- `\b` (the backspace character) doesn't work
- `(char)127` (the delete character) doesn't work

That said, if your passwords can have backslashes (`\`) in them, that can absolutely be a problem. `\` in Java is used to denote a special character, with the following character. The string `"nnn"` is just `"nnn"`, but `"n\nn"` is

```
 n
 n
```

Because `\n` represents a newline, the third n is lost.

There are many specialty characters denoted like this, but more importantly your passwords really can't have `\` in them without causing issues. Either you're getting an escape character if the following character if the following character with a backslash is legal [(and `\1` actually is)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616286/what-does-1-represent-in-this-java-string), or it won't print if it's not legal.

Comment: I am using a program written in Java. I have created a password. My password contains those characters. I think those characters are causing my password to have issues because it is having an effect on the characters following it. I could just change my password, but I wanted to see if this was the problem first.

Comment: What are sort of things you want to ignore? Do you have a list of such characters?

Comment: I don't want to ignore anything. I have a value set to "\*" (without the quotes) and I think that is causing me problems. Is using a backward slash a bad idea? Let's say I create a user login on a program using Java. Wouldn't this cause issues? Like if I made my username "L\unchBox."

Comment: @Mshnik, what if I did something that typically didn't have any meaning. Like you said, "\n" starts a new line, but what about something like "\9" or "\1" etc? Would this still cause problems?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this same problem using Java 8:

```
    List<String> ignore = Arrays.asList("r", "2", "3");
    String text = "Hello world 1 2 3";
    text=toRemove.stream().map(toRem-> (Function<String,String>)s->s.replaceAll(toRem, "")).reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen).apply(text);
    System.out.println(text);
```

Output:

```
Hello wold 1
```